# Converting unusaul height format in R

Tags: r

So I am working with some BRFSS data and they have height as 510 when instead of 5'10" how could I convert this using R to total inches
race

```
weight Height BMI
 155    510  2224
 180    510  2583
 175    504  3004
 194    503  3437
 165    506  2663
 210    510  3013
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring` to get the first digit (the number of feet), then multiply that by 12 to convert to inches, then use `substring` again to get the last two digits (already in inches) and add them together to get total height in inches

```
df <- read_table("
 weight Height BMI
 155    510    2224
 180    510    2583
 175    504    3004
 194    503    3437
 165    506    2663
 210    510    3013")

df$Height_Inch <- as.numeric(substring(df$Height, 1, 1)) * 12 + as.numeric(substring(df$Height, 2))

df
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  weight Height   BMI Height_Inch
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1    155    510  2224          70
2    180    510  2583          70
3    175    504  3004          64
4    194    503  3437          63
5    165    506  2663          66
6    210    510  3013          70
```

Answer (score 0):

The vectorized function below assumes that the two last digits are the inches value and all others prior to those the feet values. It mutiplies the latter by 12 and adds the former.

```
toInches <- function(x){
  a <- as.integer(substr(x, 1, nchar(x) - 2))*12
  b <- as.integer(substring(x, nchar(x) - 1))
  a + b
}

toInches(df1$Height)
#[1] 70 70 64 63 66 70
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
 weight Height BMI
 155    510    2224
 180    510    2583
 175    504    3004
 194    503    3437
 165    506    2663
 210    510    3013
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `transform`, e.g.,

```
transform(df, Height_Inch = (Height%/%100)*12+Height%%100)
```

such that

```
> transform(df, Height_Inch = (Height%/%100)*12+Height%%100)
  weight Height  BMI Height_Inch
1    155    510 2224          70
2    180    510 2583          70
3    175    504 3004          64
4    194    503 3437          63
5    165    506 2663          66
6    210    510 3013          70
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(weight = c(155L, 180L, 175L, 194L, 165L, 210L), 
    Height = c(510L, 510L, 504L, 503L, 506L, 510L), BMI = c(2224L,
    2583L, 3004L, 3437L, 2663L, 3013L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```